how to do a table means using gtsummary
I would like to make a table of means with CIs or median and quartiles of a continuous variable for several categorical variables.
The model table shows my expectation with the result.
I need to do this for a survey data.
I did several searches but didn't find a solution in gtsummary.
Desired result
            BMI CI95%
Sex Male    26  
    Female  28  
Age groups  
    20-39   24  
    40-59   26  
    60 or + 28  `

